# How can I remove my overlay in css as soon as I delete all rows in datatables table (jquery)?

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I have a data table which appears after user selects the hyperlink. It contains some rows and each row has a possibility of removal itself. This is how I do the removing part:

```
$('.remove').on('click',function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Also, showing the table works with this:

```
$("#trigger-overlay2").click(function() {
    $(".overlay-boxify2").toggleClass("open");
});
```

So how can I remove the overlay as soon as I remove all the rows in a table?

Currently the table stays empty, user can see only header of it...

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fyw6kajm/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a function to count how many rows are in the tbody of the table, if the tbody has no children ('s) anymore, hide the overlay / remove the table:

```
function checkTableLength() {
    var tableLength = $('table tbody > tr').length;
    if (tableLength === 0) {
        $('.overlay-boxify2').toggleClass('open');
        // Remove the table
        $('table').remove();
    }
}

$('.remove').on('click',function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    checkTableLength();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.remove').on('click',function(){
    // Get the tbody tag
    var tbody = $(this).closest('tr').parent();
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    // If there are no more rows, hide the overlay
    if (!tbody.children().length)
        $('.overlay-boxify2').toggleClass('open');
});
```